# JSON Config Handler in C# with simple key-value update mechanism

Tags: c#

I'm trying to simplify my json config file handler. I want to 'expose' the properties defined in the configuration class. I can load propierties like:

```
string s = (ConfigurationHandler.Load(path).SomeStringValue);
```

now i want to achieve a similar behavior like commented in the code.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
namespace JsonConfigHandler
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration { SomeBoolValue = true, SomeIntValue = 100, SomeStringValue = "Hello" };
            string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            ConfigurationHandler.Save(configuration, $@"{path}\config.json");
            // now i only want to update one configuration element like SomeStringValue and then save it - how can i simplify this?
            // in this sample i do already have the Configuration loaded. But in a complex solution, whenever i quickly want to update one/multiple settings
            // i always have to load the configuraiton first, update the loaded configuration.key/element, set the value for the key/element, save it again. 
            // how can i 'expose' these setting-elements/keys to easily update them in one line of code like:
            // ConfigurationHandler.UpdateConfigSetting("Key", "Value");
            configuration.SomeStringValue = "Goodbye";
            ConfigurationHandler.Save(configuration, $@"{path}\config.json");
        }
    }
    public static class ConfigurationHandler
    {
        public static Configuration Load(string path)
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Configuration>(File.ReadAllText(path));
        }
        public static void Save(Configuration conf, string path)
        {
            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(path))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(conf, Formatting.Indented));
            }
        }
    }
    public class Configuration 
    {
        public string SomeStringValue { get; set; }
        public int SomeIntValue { get; set; }
        public bool SomeBoolValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to update the configuration file without loading it? Even if we ignore validation, how would we know where in the file to start writing? Are you trying to avoid loading the file for performance reasons?

Comment: @AluanHaddad, i just want to have a one-liner to update the config file. as mentioned in the sample like: ConfigurationHandler.UpdateConfigSetting("Key", "Value");
i'm just not getting it to work. i mean, the logic in the ConfigurationHandler class.

Comment: What's the trouble with your solution?

Comment: What you try to do is already implemented in `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`, the configuration middleware in .NET Core and all .NET Framework versions that support .NET Standard (ie all supported versions). This includes reloading modified config files. The only part that's missing is modifying the stored configuration, something that *shouldn't* be part of the configuration middleware itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to hold the current configuration in the configuration handler and use reflection for updating the values.

See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8ToVkK

The `UpdateConfig` method would look something like this then

```
    // Change config for a single key value pair.
    public static void UpdateConfig(string key, object value)
    {
        UpdateConfigSetting(key, value);
        Save(Config);
    }

    // Change config for a set of key value pairs.
    public static void UpdateConfig(Dictionary<string, object> configChanges)
    {
        foreach (var configChange in configChanges)
        {
            UpdateConfigSetting(configChange.Key, configChange.Value);
        }

        Save(Config);
    }

    // Use reflection to change the value in the configuration instance.
    private static void UpdateConfigSetting(string key, object value)
    {
        try
        {
            var property = Config.GetType().GetProperty(key);
            property.SetValue(Config, value, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // That probably happens, if the given property does not exist on
            // Configuration or the type is different and cannot be converted.
            // Think about how to react in that case depending on your application.
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you're going to support arbitrary keys and values, just use a `Dictionary<string, object>`. Also, your exception handling should be revised or removed

Comment: I missed the part of the question about multiple changes at once. I added it and made the exception issue more clear.